# how to extract dynamic part in SIRD router (Simple Router)

Tags: playframework-2.6

I have created a `SIRD` router

```
class UserRouter @Inject()(controller:UserController) extends SimpleRouter {

  override def routes:Routes = {
    case GET (p"/signup/:token") =>{  //corresponds to email verification from user after sign up. This was the URL which the server had sent
      println("add user request with token"); //TODOM - print token
      controller.verifyUser(); //
    }

  }
}
```

The code in `routes.conf` to use the `SIRD` router is

```
->      /ws/users                      WSRouters.UserRouter #use UserRouter for /ws/users
```

The action is

```
  def verifyUser(token:String) = Action.async{
    implicit request => {
      println("verifyUser action called with token: "+token) //TODOM - add proper handling and response
      Future(Ok("user verified"))
    }
  }
```

how do I extract the dynamic part from the url (`token`) in `case GET (p"/signup/:token")` and pass it to `verifyUser`? In normal `routes.conf`. I can simply do something like `GET    /home/:id                    controllers.HomeController.index2(id)` but when I do the same thing in `SIRD` router, I get error that `token` is not defined

```
case GET (p"/signup/:token") =>{  //corresponds to email verification from user after sign up. This was the URL which the server had sent
      println("add user request with token"); //TODOM - print token
      controller.verifyUser(token); //COMPILE ERROR - token is undefined.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct way is to use `$token` instead of `:token`

```
case GET (p"/signup/$token") =>{  //corresponds to email verification from user after sign up. This was the URL which the server had sent
      println("add user request with token"+token); //TODOM - print token
      controller.verifyUser(token); //
    }
```